# “AddThis” Sharing Button : How to change from Http to Https

Tags: magento-1.9, https, third-party-module

I'm working on Magento 1.9.2 with AddThis Social Sharing, I had inserted and changed URL from http tp https on our magento site. But it still display http on src:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid="></script>`

I want to change http to https on this src. Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script from http to // only. it will get dynamically way if it is http or https

```
//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js
```